# getting notified about arriving ethernet-frames on Linux

Tags: c++, unix, raw-ethernet

I need to be notified when a Ethernet Frame is arriving on a UNIX system (on eth0 port). Is there a way to register my function somewhere? currently i'm working with the "sys/socket.h"-Library but i can't find a function to register myself.

Comment: you could checkout libpcap for this

Comment: Some interesting read on the subject by the author of curl : https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html